# Bloquear o duplo clique do botão com parsley

Tags: html, parsley

Eu uso a biblioteca parsley.js e quero desabilitar o duplo clique para impedir cadastrar duas vezes no banco, mas dá conflito porque o parsley já bloqueia automaticamente quando dá erro.
Eu quero que quando não houver erros indicado no parsley.js aí sim bloqueie o botão submit

Answer (score 0):

De uma olhada se é isso que você precisa:
http://jonleigh.me/preventing-duplicate-form-submissions-with-parsley/